# Highlight mean value on y-axis in bar chart

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

So I have a bar chart with y-axis value 
`y = [0:20:40:60:100]` 
as set by bar chart by default. Now I need to mark the **mean y value** of my bars, so suppose it is 54.5.

I need **54.5** on my axis.
I don't want (0, 54.5) to be marked with some sign, 
I need (0, 54.5) to show the value 54.5, so that I  can numerically identify the mean.

Any advicein this regard will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%random example data
data=rand(10,1)
%create bar plot
bar(data)
%insert mean
m=mean(data)
%draw mean line
line(xlim,[m,m])
%add mean to yticks to show on axis.
set(gca,'YTick',union(get(gca,'YTick'),m))
```

[image]