# Adding mean value to y-axis in plot

Tags: r, plot, graph, statistics, mean

I want the mean of the sample to be shown on my y-axis. I tried doing it like they have explained it in  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330754/highlight-mean-value-on-y-axis-in-bar-chart) but it does not seem to work. If you look at the  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSnsy.jpg), the red line represents the mean. I just need the value to be shown on the y-axis. Any help is appreciated.

My R code:

```
xyear = seq(1920,1978,1)
plot(xyear,difference, type = "bar", col = "blue", main = "Difference between precipitation in winter and summer", xlab = "Year", ylab = "Difference")
abline(difference.mean, 0, col = "red")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
xyear = seq(1920,1978,1)
plot(xyear,difference, type = "bar", col = "blue", main = "Difference between precipitation in winter and summer", xlab = "Year", ylab = "Difference")
abline(mean(difference), 0, col = "red")
axis(side = 2, at=mean(difference), labels=T)
```

`axis` command should help in this case. For more information, [this page](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html) may be helpful.